# Calendar on SharePoint Online that you wish to view and access in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, outlook, events, copy-content

I have connected a SP Calendar to outlook using Connect to Outlook, simply followed this, [Connect to Outlook](https://www.puryear-it.com/connect-a-sharepoint-calendar-to-outlook) . I can see the SP calendar on outlook, i can copy the Outlook calendar events to SharePoint. But the problem is, the event is just a copy, if i update my Outlook calendar event, it wont be updated on SharePoint.

Is there a way to handle this, such if i set up a connection and if i update any event on Outlook calendar, it should roll up to my SP Calendar?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks